# Can I test if a script is authorised and call the Google authorisation dialog if not?

Tags: google-apps-script

My users are going to have to authorise script in new spreadsheets every 4 weeks. I'd like to call the authorisation dialog as soon as they open a spreadsheet for the first time and NOT call it if the script has already been authorised.

At present, the simplest way I've found to do this is to get them to click a "Go to Main Sheet" button (i.e. a drawing with an attached script) on a blank sheet. If they've already authorised they get taken straight to Main, if not it triggers the authorisation notice - in which case they end up having to click the "Go to Main Sheet" button a second time after they've authorised.

I don't like it, it's clunky. Is there a way to test if the script needs authorising and call the dialog directly, e.g. from an onOpen event?

Comment: Your workaround is not so bad ;-) You could also delete this first blank sheet in a function that runs only when authorized so you would get rid of this warning ...

Comment: Thanks Serge... I need to ask more but I hit enter by accident so I'll start again

Comment: *Made the same mistake twice - red face!* Sadly, deleting the sheet isn't an option in my use case because approximately 30 users need to use my spreadsheets with "Can Edit" privileges during the first 4 weeks after its creation. That's Phase 1. In Phase 2 the blank sheet gets deleted as you suggest. I'm intrigued by your phrase "a function that runs only when authorized". That's the very thing I'd find it very useful to be able to test for but I don't know how to achieve it other than the concept that no function runs unless authorised. Can you offer any further advice?

Comment: this is what I was thinking about [(link to example spreadsheet)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dGV3ejdXbXQzeEpxRnpTbkx2dzdpeWc) but it works only for single user.

Comment: finally I wrote an 'answer' to be able to show the code properly...

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution for single user to make authorization process simple and obvious.
I know it's not going to meet your use case since you have multiple users on the same spreadsheet but it can have parts that you could be interested in.

Here is the code and the [example SS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dGV3ejdXbXQzeEpxRnpTbkx2dzdpeWc) (make a copy of it to get edit access and don't forget it works only one time! (at least as far as the authorization is concerned, you can always undo the sheet deletion !!))

```
function onOpen(){
    if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNumSheets()==1){  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "test", functionName: "test"},
                     ];
  ss.addMenu("Recherche",menuEntries);// custom menu
                     }
} // menu appears only if authorization has been processed

function test(){
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNumSheets()==2){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);// make first sheet active to be sure
  var del = ss.deleteActiveSheet();
  onOpen;
  }
  Logger.log(findThelastRow('d',0))
    }
//
//
    function findThelastRow(column,index){
              var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
              var lastRow = doc.getSheets()[index].getLastRow()+1;// check last row on the appropriate sheet
              var coldata = doc.getSheets()[index].getRange(column+2+':'+column+lastRow).getValues();// I begin on Row 2 just as you did
          for(i=coldata.length-1;i>=0;i--){
             if(coldata[i][0]!=''){return i+2;break}
          }
          return 0;
        }
```

NOTE the functions I have put in this example are just examples !

The important thing is the part that deletes first sheet when authorization is done. Hoping this will be clear enough ;-)